# How to save post into Django (2.0) like I bookmarked it

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

How to save a post into Django (2.0) like I bookmarked that post for later usage. I need to implement it into one of my project.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to address this problem.

1. You can build up your Bookmark model which saves the arguments needed for that request. Once user selects bookmark from UI, you fetch the arguments from DB and pass that to your view and redirect user to necessary page.
2. If you just  want that user has all arguments loaded on page he/she last visited and not to save anything in db, you can use django sessions. For more info check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#examples)